# Enumerate 2D array and append to new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, enumeration, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to enumerate a 2D NumPy array of shape (512, 512) with pixel values, to output `[y_index, x_index, pixel_value]`. Output array should have shape (262144, 3): 262144 pixels from 512x512 matrix and 3 for columns `pixel value`, `y coordinate` and `x coordinate`.

I used `ndenumerate` but how to store values in an array? My attempt at last line is incorrect:

```
img = as_np_array[:, :, 0]
img = img.reshape(512, 512)
coordinates = np.empty([262,144, 3])
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(img):
    coordinates = np.append(coordinates, [[x], index[0], index[1]])
```

Intel Core i7 2.7GHz (4 cores) takes 7-10 minutes. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Can't you use three variables for pixel value, x coordinate and y coordinate. In that case, you can use the existing array, and `ycoord, xcoord = numpy.mgrid[0:img.shape[0],0:img.shape[1]]`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry, but I didn't understand your particular format of answer. Basically I need an array output with 3 columns: `pixel value`, and its `x` & `y` coordinates. Reason I need that format specifically is because I need to then save it as a CSV file to have that specific data format/structure. You have `ycoord`, `xcoord` but I need everything in one array output.

Comment: Not necessarily: you could also create a double loop over the x- and y-coordinates, and then output a line of x, y, pixel_value to the CSV file. In which case, you neither need that large a 2D array, nor my solution, but just something like `for x in range(512): for y in range(512): csv.write(x, y, img[y,x])`.

Comment: Many thanks for this suggestion. I'm just trying out this code right now. I tried this code as a test run with a small array example: `array2 = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
with open('csv_test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(['x_coord', 'y_coord', 'pixel_value'])
    for y in np.nditer(array2): 
        for x in np.nditer(y): 
            thewriter.writerow([x, y, array2[y,x]])`, but I got the error: `index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3`. Not sure why is that? Is `np.nditer` the issue or is it something else?

Comment: Because `np.nditer` steps through the flattened array, which is larger than one dimension. Also, your code doesn't not reflect what I wrote. I step through the dimensions (shape) of the array; you step through the array itself, and use the values *inside* the to index the array: `for y in np.nditer(array2): ... array2[y,x]`. That's not going to work (except in some very special cases).

Comment: That makes sense with regards to `np.nditer`. I realise now, after looking at examples of `np.nditer`, how it exactly works. I didn't quite understand its documentation alone very well. With regards to the solution, I used `for index, pix in np.ndenumerate(img):`, and simply extracted the data to be written to a CSV file now and it works like a treat. I've got exactly what I want now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can self answer your question with your solution, so that at least, it shows this problem has found a solution. (If you answer it, you can also remove your edit to your question about the duplicate, since it has been unlocked again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is this:

```
with open('img_pixel_coor1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    headernames = ['y_coord', 'x_coord', 'pixel_value']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headernames)
    thewriter.writeheader()     
    for index, pix in np.ndenumerate(img):
        thewriter.writerow({'y_coord' : index[0], 'x_coord' : index[1], 'pixel_value' : pix})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`numpy.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to do this. What you want ultimately is `image_data` with `y`, `x` indices and the corresponding pixels (`px`). There are three columns in `image_data`.

```py
row, col = np.indices(img.shape)
y, x, px = row.flatten(), col.flatten(), img.flatten()
image_data = np.array([y, x, px]).T
```

## Detailed Example:

```py
img = np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4)

def process_image_data(img):
    row, col = np.indices(img.shape)
    return (row.flatten(), col.flatten(), img.flatten())

y, x, px = process_image_data(img)
```